# R: How to write a function that replaces a function call with another function call?

Tags: r, nse

E.g. I want to transform the code

```
mean(x)
```

to

```
fn(x)
```

everytime I see `mean` in the code.

```
replace_mean <- function(code) {
  substitute(code, list(mean = fn)) # doesn't work
  substitute(substitute(code), list(mean = fn)) # doesn't work
}
```

the above two approaches don't work. E.g.

```
replace_mean(list(mean(y), mean(x)))
```

What's the best way to do function replacement using NSE in R?

Base R Solutions preferred.

**Update example output**

```
replace(mean(x)) # fn(x)

replace(list(a = mean(x), mean(ok))) # list(a=fn(x), fn(ok)))
```

Comment: Can you share few examples with expected output ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The following function, when passed `mean(x)` and some `fn` such as `sqrt` as its two arguments returns the call object `fn(x)`, i.e. `sqrt(x)`, replacing occurrences of `mean` with `fn`.

```
replace_mean <- function(code, fn) {
  do.call("substitute", list(substitute(code), list(mean = substitute(fn))))
}
```

### Examples

**1) Basic example**

```
e <- replace_mean(mean(x), sqrt)
e
## sqrt(x)

x <- 4
eval(e)
## [1] 2
```

**2) more complex expression**

```
ee <- replace_mean(mean(x) + mean(x*x), sqrt)
ee
## sqrt(x) + sqrt(x * x)

x <- 4
eval(ee)
## [1] 6
```

**3) apply replace_mean to body of f creating g**

```
f <- function(x) mean(x) + mean(x*x)
g <- f
body(g) <- do.call("replace_mean", list(body(f), quote(sqrt)))

g
## function (x) 
## sqrt(x) + sqrt(x * x)

x <- 4
g(x)
## [1] 6
```

Comment: Great answer! What would be awesome if the "why"s can be slightly explored. I know there is Hadley's Advance R (https://adv-r.hadley.nz/metaprogramming.html)  but after reading it I still couldn't get this right so this answer is pretty awesome!

Comment: The two inner `substitute` calls grab the two arguments using nonstandard evaluation.  We need to use `do.call` with the outer `substitute` to force its first argument to be evaluated; otherwise, it would just return literally `substitute(code)`

Answer (score 0):

One way is much more ugly and relies on string manipulation to generate the code you want to run and then evaluating it.

```
replace_mean <- function(code) {
  code_subbed = substitute(code)

  # constructu the code I want
  code_subbed_subbed = sprintf("substitute(%s, list(mean=quote(fn)))", deparse(code_subbed))

  eval(parse(text = code_subbed_subbed))
}

replace_mean(list(mean(x), a=  mean(ok)))
```