# build a call using a recursive function

Tags: r, recursion

I'm trying to write a recursive function that builds a nested `ifelse` `call`. I do realize there are much better approaches than nested `ifelse`, e.g., `dplyr::case_when` and `data.table::fcase`, but I'm trying to learn how to approach such problems with metaprogramming.

The following code builds out the nested `ifelse`, but I'm struggling to `substitute` `data` with the actual supplied value, in this case `my_df`.

If I replace `quote(data)` with `substitute(data)`, it only works for the first `ifelse`, but after entering the next iteration, it turns into `data`.

I think something like `pryr::modify_lang` could solve this after the fact, but I think there's probably a base R solution someone knows.

```
my_df <- data.frame(group = letters[1:3],
                    value = 1:3)

build_ifelse <- function(data, by, values, iter=1){
  
  x <- call("ifelse",
            call("==",
                 call("[[", quote(data), by),
                 values[iter]),
            1,
            if(iter != length(values)) build_ifelse(data, by, values, iter = iter + 1) else NA)
  return(x)
}

build_ifelse(data = my_df, by = "group", values = letters[1:3])
# ifelse(data[["group"]] == "a", 1, ifelse(data[["group"]] == "b", 
#        1, ifelse(data[["group"]] == "c", 1, NA)))
```

Thanks for any input!

Edit:

I found this question/answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59242109/9244371

Based on that, I found a solution that seems to work pretty well:

```
build_ifelse <- function(data, by, values, iter=1){
  
  x <- call("ifelse",
            call("==",
                 call("[[", quote(data), by),
                 values[iter]),
            1,
            if(iter != length(values)) build_ifelse(data, by, values, iter = iter + 1) else NA)
  
  x <- do.call(what = "substitute",
               args = list(x, 
                           list(data = substitute(data))))
  return(x)
}

build_ifelse(data = my_df, by = "group", values = letters[1:3])
# ifelse(my_df[["group"]] == "a", 1, ifelse(my_df[["group"]] == 
#     "b", 1, ifelse(my_df[["group"]] == "c", 1, NA)))

eval(build_ifelse(data = my_df, by = "group", values = letters[1:3]))
# [1] 1 1 1
```

Comment: You are creating a call, You might consider using an iteration rather than recursion

Comment: What are you trying to come up with?

Comment: I really want to build a nested `ifelse` for use with the `h2o` package. In that case `h2o.ifelse`. `h2o` doesn't have a case when so i was trying to build my own. Left out these details in my original post thinking it would simplify my question to exclude.

Answer (score 0):

There is a base function, `switch`, that can deliver sequential testing and results similar to `dplyr::case_when`, at least when used with a loop wrapper. It's not well documented. It is really two different functions, one that expects a numeric input for it classification variable and another that expects character values. I can never remember it's name, and so typically I need to remind myself that it is referenced in the `?Control` page.  Since you're using character values, here goes. (I changed the outputs so you can see that some degree of substitution is occurring and that there is an "otherwise" option

```
sapply( my_df$group, switch,  a=4, b=5, d=6, NA) 
 a  b  c 
 4  5 NA
```

Comment: Thanks for this answer. The combination of `sapply` and `switch` does seem quite handy. In my case though, I'd like to be able to build the call dynamically. I won't know things in advance like the name of the `data.frame`, what column they're testing values of (`by`), or what they want to submit in the `yes` case.